# Assign Common ID to multiple row insert from MySQL array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that inserts rows into a table based on selected rows from a MySQL array.

the code to insert the rows into the new table is:

```
$sql="insert into loaddetails (CaseNo,GrossMass,CaseStatus,Customer)
select `case no`,`gross mass`,`case status`, customer from
availablestock where `case no` = '$val'";
```

I want to assign all the inserted rows the same ID so that multiple `stock` items share the same LoadID.

How can I modify my code to do this so all the inserted records share the same ID and the ID is unique to the load.

I thought I could use the code below to get the max id and increment it by one

```
SELECT max(loadid)+1 from loaddetails
```

How can I acheive this? I realise my PHP code is not perfect but it is functional, I just need to add the functionality to allow for the rows to be inserted with a common ID to produce a result as below:

[image]

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Regards,
Ryan Smith

Complete code is:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password")or die("cannot connect");    
    mysql_select_db("databasename")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT `case no`,`customer`,`gross mass`, `case status` from availablestock where transporttypename= 'localpmb'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="form1" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>Case Number</td>
                        <td>Customer</td>    
                        <td>Weight</td> 
                        <td>Status</td> 
                    </tr>
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name=check[]  value="<?php echo $rows['case no']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['case no']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['customer']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['gross mass']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['case status']; ?></td>
                    </tr>                                   

<?php
    }
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="planlocalpmb" type="submit" id="planlocalpmb" value="planlocalpmb"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php



                            $check=$_POST['check'];

                        if($_REQUEST['planlocalpmb']=='planlocalpmb'){
 {
                            $sql="insert into loaddetails (CaseNo,GrossMass,CaseStatus,Customer) select `case no`,`gross mass`,`case status`, customer from availablestock where `case no` = '$val'";

                            foreach($check as $key=>$value)
                            {
                            $sql="insert into loaddetails (CaseNo,GrossMass,CaseStatus,Customer) select `case no`,`gross mass`,`case status`, customer from availablestock where `case no` = '$value'";
                            $final=mysql_query($sql);
                            if($final)
                            {
                            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=php.php\">";
                            }                                            } 
                                }
                                }
                    // Check if delete button active, start this



// if successful redirect to php.php

mysql_close();
?>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do u want to assign same load id to all rows?? or what is common thing with same load ID??

Comment: Hi, for all selected rows from the array, when inserted into the new table should have the same loadid. loadid is the common link so one loadid will have multiple cases on it. the loadid represents a physical truck and the cases the stock on the truck. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO loaddetails (LoadID, CaseNo, GrossMass, CaseStatus, Customer)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(loadid)+1 FROM loaddetails) LoadID, CaseNo, GrossMass, CaseStatus, Customer
FROM availablestock WHERE CaseNo = '$val'
```

Make sure LoadID has an index!

You may need to lock the table first. I'm not sure.

I didn't check the rest of your code, but I do notice you have an SQL Injection vulnerability there.

Comment: Hi All, @Ariel. Thanks for the reply and advice. The query you gave me works 100% correctly in PHPMyAdmin. when I insert  the query into my PHP code, it no longer works. If I replace the variable in the PHP Code, the rows are inserted into the mysql table however the LoadID field increments by 1 for each row where in mysql all rows are assigned the same ID. Any ideas on how to modify the PHP code so it works? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing this insert in a loop? Each cycle through the loop will increment by one.

Comment: Hi All, @Ariel. To be honest I am not entirely sure as I am a real novice however I do think it is being processed in the loop. With the MySQL script you privided, I have got the PHP script to execute the MySQL insert statement. The output however in the MySQL table does not contain a common ID but an incremented ID. I need all the inserted rows to share the same ID. Please advise where I am going wrong. Thanks, Ryan

Comment: @Smudger I apparently didn't notice your last message, so hopefully you got everything working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
INSERT INTO loaddetails 
  (LoadID, CaseNo, GrossMass, CaseStatus, Customer)
SELECT  m.NewLoadId, CaseNo, GrossMass, CaseStatus, Customer
FROM availablestock 
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(loadid)+1 AS NewLoadId 
      FROM loaddetails
    ) AS m
WHERE CaseNo = '$val'
```

Comment: Hi All, ypercube. I did try as you advise and it does work from the PHP Script. the issue however is that the output in the mysql table does not have a common id for all inserted rows. As per @Ariel above, this is most likely a result of the loop. How can I modify the PHP to process all rows with the same loadid. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, you mean that you have many `$val` values and you process each one with a separate call.

Comment: Hi, I think you are right. How can I acheive my gols of assigning one common id to all inserted rows from $val?